# Custom authentication with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am currently working on a big software project that makes use of Firebase services. Especially Firebase Cloud Firestore, Firebase Storage, and Firebase Auth is used.

#### Multiple teams in one project

Teams can create their instance of the app to use the features of the app. From a technical standpoint, it is important to know that everything happens through one single Firebase project. Teams are not separated into multiple projects. From a feature standpoint, this is mandatory.

#### The authentication process

Admins of a team can manage the experience for the users of their team. They should also be able to modify the login methods and e.g. set up individual data to their Microsoft Azure AD account or Google Enterprise account. After a successful setup users of the team should be able to sign in with the prepared auth method by their team admin.

#### Possible approach

All available auth methods are enabled, set up, and ready to use (E-Mail, Google, Twitter, Microsoft, etc.). When a user opens the app and wants to sign in, the app checks which auth methods are enabled by the team admin and presents the appropriate UI.

#### Problem: Microsoft AD

Unfortunately, the metadata and values needed for Microsoft AD are set by the team admins and are different for every team. How can this be solved?